# A question about the Riemann Integrability

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if a function is continuous on a closed interval, then it is integrable. But I have a question that how to apply it to an infinite situation. I.e. $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\;\mathrm{d}x$.
Can I also use this theorem? But I'm not sure this interval here not closed right? So I don't know if it is right.

Comment: It wasn't very courteous to edit the question to a different one.

Comment: ??????????????????

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use that theorem here. For example $f(x)=1$ is continuous but $\int_0^{\infty} dx=\infty$, i.e. $f(x)$ is not integrable on $[0,\infty)$.

More formally, $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$ doesn't exist in a Riemann sense for ANY $f(x)$. What this is shorthand for is $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} \int_0^t f(x) dx$. So if $f(x)$ is continuous on some finite interval, then it is integrable on that interval. However the limit as the size of that interval increases might not exist.